# Oracle DBMS_LOB to Postgres Conversion

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Can someone please let me know how to convert the below Oracle code from Oracle to Postgres Database   : dbms_lob.writeappend() append()  trim()  write()

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  l_1 clob;
  l_2 clob;
  amount number;
  offset number;
begin
 select in_lob into l_1
 from test.lob_table
 where id=2 for update;
  amount:=2;
  offset:=3;
 dbms_lob.writeappend(l_1,length('hhhhhhhh'),'hhhhhhhh');
   dbms_output.put_line(l_1);
end;
```